# Unable to fetch data from Redux store and update in UI component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I am new to Redux, am building a tracker app but I have been stacked for days. I would very much appreciate it if I could get help from you. Thanks

`store.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = { };
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), // store enhancer func
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()),
);

export default store;
```

`waterReducer.js`

```
import { GET_WATER,  ADD_WATER } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  water: [],
  loading: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {                                           
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_WATER:
      return {
        ...state,
        water: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case ADD_WATER:
      return {
        ...state,
        water: [action.payload, ...state.water || {}],
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`addWaterActions.js`

```
const defaultURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

const myLibrary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myLibrary')) || []

const addWaters = waterData => async dispatch => {
  const apiConfig = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  };
  try {
    const water = await axios.post(`${defaultURL}/waters`, waterData, apiConfig);
    myLibrary.push(water.data);
    localStorage.setItem('myLibrary', JSON.stringify(myLibrary));
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_WATER,
      payload: water.data,
    });
    return water.data;

  } catch(error) {
    dispatch({
      type: WATERS_ERRORS,
      payload: error
    });
  }
};
```

`addWaterComponent.js`

```
import { addWaters } from '../../redux/actions/waterActions';

const AddWater = ({ addWaters }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    amount: '',
    total: '',
  });
  const {
    amount, total,
  } = formData;
  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addWaters({
      id: uuidv1(),
      amount,
      total,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AddWrap>
        <TrackWater>
          Add Water
        </TrackWater>
        <CenterW>
          
          <FormWrap onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <AmountInp
              type="number"
              name="amount"
              value={amount}
              onChange={onChange}
              placeholder="Amount"
              required
            />
            <TotalInp
              type="number"
              name="total"
              placeholder="Water Target"
              value={total}
              onChange={onChange}
              required
            />
            <SubmitData type="submit" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              Add Water to Data
            </SubmitData>
          </FormWrap>
        </CenterW>
      </AddWrap>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

AddWater.propTypes = {
  addWaters: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  water: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  water: state.water.water,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addWaters })(AddWater);
```

[Redux dev tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/694U9.png) [localStorage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnmIv.png)
What this code has achieved 1. Dispatch data to localStorage
2. Dispatch data to Redux dev tools

My problem: I want to read the data from the store to the component, but when I console.log(store.getState().water); the state is empty. I really need your help guys. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The store the js is can be configured this way
`const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));`
the applyMiddleware is just an enhancer to enable you dispatch an action to your store via the reducer.
console.log(`action.playload`), then make sure in the reducer you equate the actual data to the water attribute.
I suspect
`case GET_WATER: return { ...state, water: action.water, loading: false, };`
should work, I suspect that is where the error is coming from, don't forget to map state to props to access data.